# Regarding 'concoursis' duplicate

Tags: discussion, moderation, duplicate-questions

This question

[What's the name of the process by which the scriptures were written down?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/32556/whats-the-name-of-the-process-by-which-the-scriptures-were-written-down)

is not a duplicate of this question

[What does it mean that all scripture is God-Breathed?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/12090/what-does-it-mean-that-all-scripture-is-god-breathed)

Not hardly. Not even remotely.

So, I did my best to re-ask the original question, which I deleted, word for word. I don't think it's necessary for me to wait for a vote to get answers for this question or suggestions from the community about what the word might be.

Comments, David Stratton?

Comment: Looking at it again, it was not a duplicate.  You're right.

Answer (score 5):

Re-asking is not the right approach! You can disagree (and in this case I agree with you this wasn't a duplicate) but don't abuse the system. Questions can be re-opened if appropriate. Commenting, flagging, and/or asking on meta is fine. Deleting and re-posting is not.

I'm merging your two questions, although I think Flimzy has pointed out a legitimate problem with the question than you should add as a clarification ASAP. Namely: what sort of inspiration was being discussed? If you want to know the name for something you have to describe it in more detail. Right now you've gotten about as far as "What's that thing called that's puts stuff on paper made out of metal?", but that could be an offset printing press or a typewriter or a ballpoint pen. You really haven't given anybody enough description to point you to the name of the right thing.

Comment: I agree, and I knew it was brash. I just really wanted input from the community right then, and the question was so clearly _not_ a duplicate that I knew it would all be sorted out in a few hours- probably faster than it would have been successfully voted to reopen.

Comment: In my opinion, it's grossly abusive for a moderator to close a brand new question (it may have been a few minutes old?) without attempting to resolve the perceived issue. If he would have engaged in any discussion whatsoever with me, being reasonable, he would have made the same conclusion the rest of us have.

Comment: @Andrew Well please don't do that sort of thing again. You just make more work for others who have to sort it out and clean up after you. And it wasn't actual that obviously not a duplicate considering your original title and vagueness. Next time address the concerns and fix the problems instead of passing the buck. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: @Andrew You're wrong, that is not abuse. Closing questions that are unclear or appear to be duplicate or are off topic is something that should be done sooner rather than later -- otherwise people waste time composing answers that may not stick around which is a waste of their time. Moderators and the community are well within site guidelines to close such questions. If you think they've erred there are normal channels to deal with that, and your impatience is not a valid excuse for side stepping the normal procedure and making more work for everybody else.

Comment: _He was wrong_, and the question was closed in the first place, I can only figure, because he didn't read the question. The title was not vague but asked "What is the process by which ... " which is the very thing the new question asked, identically. If he would have read the question without prejudging it, he would have seen that I was asking for the name, a strictly valid one word answer both to the title and the question as it was asked.

Comment: As a member of the community I reserve the right to ask any number of questions in any manner, if I judge them appropriate, with the help of the community. Also as a general member member of the community, I depend on the moderators to act honestly and diligently, according to the guidelines. As far as is the log is concerned, I deleted my original question, edited the title and body, and resubmitted it. I believe that's SOP for that situation, is it not?

Comment: @Andrew Mods do make mistakes; they're people too. I've seen all of them here make mistakes *and* admit it and reverse it when confronted. Unilateral closure is frustrating, but is acceptable. If you disagree with their actions you can resort to a meta post or ping them in chat. Deleting and reposting is inappropriate; because you happened to be right is irrelevant. In your defense, I did notice someone suggest that in a comment. This was an odd case.

Comment: Also, no reason to be so hasty. Getting your question up a day after you wanted will probably not affect the answers you will get. If you have external pressures for an answer, well, that really has nothing to do with the site.

Comment: One final thing: I've written a meta post for frustrated users, where moderator actions are discussed in part. [Newcomers: Be patient. You will get there if you follow our direction. Keep trying](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1927)

Comment: Sorry for suggesting that you delete and re-ask! I should've realised that isn't helpful.